# Division produces NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery, division

I'm trying to divide the variable `number` by `100` and get `NaN`. I'm new to jQuery, can anyone help me to understand what I'm doing wrong?

```
$.each(data.products, function (i, data) {

    var div_data = "<p>" + data.title + "<br/>" + data.description + "</p>";

    div_data += '<img src="' + data.imageUrl + '" title="Loading..." alt="Loading...">';
    div_data += '<p><a href="' + data.url + '">Buy</a></p>';

    $(div_data).appendTo("#testjson");

    number = '<div class="number">' + data.price + '</div>';
    $('#myElement').text((number / 100));

});
```

Comment: I don't see any JSON in your code. If you are referring to `data`, that appears to be a normal object. JSON is a textual representation of information, like XML, YAML or CSV.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you're setting `number` to a string:

```
number = '<div class="number">'+ data.price + '</div>';
```

Then you are dividing that string by `100`

In JavaScript that results in [`NaN`](http://es5.github.com/#x4.3.23) which is short for `Not a Number` . This is specified [in the spec](http://es5.github.com/#x11.5.2).

A possible solution could be to divide the number itself by 100, and not the HTML string, for example:

```
var number = data.price/100;
$('#myElement').text(number);
```

This would not attach a nested div to your `#myElement` though.

Comment: Thanks, got it, so how do I get that number from my JSON data as a number rather than a string?

Comment: @user2204755: That's not JSON, `data` is a normal object, and I think we can assume that `data.price` is a number. If it is a numeric string, the division will convert it to a number automatically.

Comment: Your data is not JSON, it's a JavaScript object, JSON is a data exchange format in which you often serialize JavaScript objets as strings. data.price seems to be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this

```
    number = '<div class="number">' + (data.price/100) + '</div>';
    $('#myElement').text((number ));
```

This is what you are doing in .text()

```
('<div class="number">' + (data.price/100) + '</div>')/100
```