# Percentage difference between two numbers equals NaN - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm calculating the difference between the two numbers I am getting from an array. I would like to get the percentage difference between the two, so my logic behind it is: `Original number / New Number * 100 = %`

I have a console log for the original number as
 `console.log(data.Results.Data[115].DataValue, "First")` which shows 1,378,637.7

I have another console log for the new number as `console.log(data.Results.Data[116].DataValue, "Second")` which equals to 1,470,393.0

I am now trying to declare a variable that would equal the percentage between these two values.

`let perChangeOne = data.Results.Data[116].DataValue / data.Results.Data[115].DataValue * 100
    console.log(perChangeOne, "%%")`

When the console.log for perChangeOne equals NaN. I am expecting to show 106.7

```
function drawPercentageDifference(data) {       
    let perChangeOne = data.Results.Data[116].DataValue / data.Results.Data[115].DataValue * 100
    console.log(perChangeOne, "%%")
    console.log(data.Results.Data[116].DataValue, "First")
    console.log(data.Results.Data[115].DataValue, "Second")
}
```

Comment: Might these `DataValue`s be strings?

Comment: The  `DataValue` are strings

Comment: `data.BEAAPI.Results...`?

Comment: BEA was a typo, shouldve been removed. Edited text to reflect that

Comment: +string / +string

Comment: @Estradiaz That does the same as `string / string`, giving `NaN` due to the `,`... `/` already coerces its operands to a number, same as the unary `+` does

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Division produces NaN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15600132/division-produces-nan)

Comment: For the comma issue, [How can I parse a string with a comma thousand separator to a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11665884/215552)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You values are probably strings, and due to the `,` they can't be coerced to a number.

You need to remove the `,`. Even though it's not strictly necessary, I'd then convert to a number explicitly as well:

```js
    function drawPercentageDifference(data) {
        const numerator = Number(data.Results.Data[116].DataValue.replace(/,/g, ''))
        const denominator = Number(data.Results.Data[115].DataValue.replace(/,/g, ''))
        const percentage = 100 * numerator / denominator
        console.log(`${percentage} % (${numerator} / ${denominator})`)
    }
```